# ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.pathname);

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to figure out a way to load my pages quicker by creating a variable newHREF and then using the `history.pushState('', '', newHREF);` to push that link to the browser after the new content is loaded. That part works fine and I am happy with that.

The problem I am having is that I am not able to track any of the new pages after the link is pushed to the browser.

I was researching Google and found that I am able to use the `ga('send', 'pageview', '/newpage');` so I created a variable named pathLink and set it to `window.location.pathname`.

Now I want to know how to insert that pathname into the ga pageview send command.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to figure it out..  It worked when i added `ga('create', 'UA-XXX-1', 'example.com');   ga('send', 'pageview', pathLink);`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the your string with the variable:

`ga('send', 'pageview', pathLink);`

Comment: I tried 
   
     `var pathLink = window.location.pathname;       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('send', 'pageview' pathLink);` 

but nothing was showing up in my GA..  am i missing something here??

Thanks

Comment: That looks good to me, are you on the right date range in GA?